# When I am trying to download files from FTP, it is downloading with 0 kb using c# programming

Tags: c#-4.0, ftp

The below is the code which I am using to download files from FTP server, in the below else part I am downloading files(.msi and .exe files), it is unable to download the full files and it containing 0kb .Stream writer needs any permissions to download files to localpath.

Firstly I am giving permissions to Ftp to get the access and later through linux d and r commands, I am using the if and else part below.If the value is d it goes to if part and if the value is r it goes to else part.
Please help me.

```
    public bool downloadnewversionftp()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "ftp path";
            networkcredential credentials = new networkcredential("userid", "password");
            ftpwebrequest listrequest = (ftpwebrequest)webrequest.create(url);
            listrequest.method = webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails;
            listrequest.usepassive = true;
            listrequest.credentials = credentials;
            list<string> lines = new list<string>();
            using (ftpwebresponse listresponse = (ftpwebresponse)listrequest.getresponse())
            {
                using (stream liststream = listresponse.getresponsestream())
                {
                    using (streamreader listreader = new streamreader(liststream))
                    {
                        while (!listreader.endofstream)
                        {
                            lines.add(listreader.readline());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] tokens = line.split(new[] { ' ' }, 9, stringsplitoptions.removeemptyentries);
                string name = tokens[8];
                string permissions = tokens[0];
                string localfilepath = path.combine("localfile path", name);
                string fileurl = url + name;

                if (permissions[0] == 'd')
                {
                    directory.createdirectory(localfilepath);
                }
                else
                {
                    ftpwebrequest downloadrequest = (ftpwebrequest)webrequest.create(fileurl);
                    downloadrequest.usepassive = true;
                    downloadrequest.usebinary = true;
                    downloadrequest.method = webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails;
                    downloadrequest.credentials = credentials;

                    using (ftpwebresponse downloadresponse = (ftpwebresponse)downloadrequest.getresponse())
                    {

                        using (streamreader downloadreader = new streamreader(downloadresponse.getresponsestream()))
                        {
                            using (streamwriter writer = new streamwriter(localfilepath))
                            {
                                writer.write(downloadreader.readtoend());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            stackframe objtrack = new stackframe();
            var methodinfo = objtrack.getmethod();
            string calssname = methodinfo.declaringtype.name;
            string methoname = methodinfo.name;
            string lineno = convert.tostring(ex.linenumber());
            log(ex.message, calssname, methoname, lineno);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can this even compile? It's all lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download a file, use `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile`, not `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails`:

```
downloadrequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```